# Load jQuery First After DOMContentLoaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to load some scripts after `DOMContentLoaded` event and I am trying to use the following script for this. I'm not sure if the following is the best way to do this but I am having an issue with the following code because I need to load jquery first because my other scripts are depend on it. I have no idea how to do this any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

```js
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = 'https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js';
      document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script);
    
      var script1 = document.createElement('script');
      script1.src = '/myscript1.js';
      document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script1);
    
      var script2 = document.createElement('script');
      script2.src = '/myscript2.js';
      document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script2);

    
    });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please know that dynamic scripts behave as `async` by default, which means that the script that loads first will also run first. So, the issue might be here that `myscript1.js` & `myscript2.js` are very small scripts and thus it loads and runs first before `jquery` script could load. To fix this you can pass `script.async=false` to each script so that script loads and run in the order they are being added to the document like:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = 'https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js';
  script.async = false;
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script);

  var script1 = document.createElement('script');
  script1.src = '/myscript1.js';
  script.async = false;
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script1);

  var script2 = document.createElement('script');
  script2.src = '/myscript2.js';
  script.async = false;
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script2);

});
```

and if you want to keep things DRY (*Don't repeat yourself*), you can use a helper function like:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  function loadScript(src) {
    let script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = src;
    script.async = false;
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script);
  }

  loadScript('https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js');
  loadScript('/myscript1.js');
  loadScript('/myscript2.js');  

});
```